# How to add a widget into central Widget using code in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I need to add a widget to the form using code, but don't by use QHBoxLayout or QVBoxLayout.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    fields[0] = new CustomLabel();
    fields[0]->setText("Hello");
    //how to show it  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `setCentralWidget()`

[documentation of setCentralWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget)

like this `ui->setCentralWidget(fields[0]);` or maybe with `this` replacing `ui`

But, to displayed many widget you have to use a widget that contains the matrix of labels (widget). When you have the parent widget that contain the matrix display it with `setCentralWidget()`